# Matrix equations?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

I came across this problem:

[image: Problem]

I have successfully found the bases of the null space but I can't seem to understand the second part. I looked around online and found nothing useful. I would appreciate some help or a link to this.

**Update:** Here is the answer to the first part, the bases of the null spaces:

[image: Bases]

Comment: Please do write in the question the basis of each kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$M(x_{1}-a)=0$$ $$M(x_2-a)=0$$ so that $$(x_1-a){\in}K_{1}$$
$$(x_2-a){\in}K_2$$
You have a basis for $K_1$ and $K_2$ so you know that: $x_1=sv+a$ where v is your 1 dimensional basis vector for $K_1$ and similarily $x_2=tu+a$ where u is your basis vector for $K_2$ (s,t are scalars). $$x_1-x_2=sv-tu$$ Using what you know about u,v and $x_1-x_2$, solve for s and t then p and q. Looking coordinate-wise, you see: 
$$p=s-t$$ $$5=s-2t$$ $$7=2s-t$$ $$q=-s+t$$
Note: It seems like the vector a does not really matter.

Comment: Why is M1(x1−a)=0 and M2(x2−a)=0? Why did we subtract? I know that if we multiply a matrix by any element in the null space, we get the zero vector. But why did we assume this?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is distributive so that $M_1(x_1-a)=0$ iff $M_1(x_1)-M_1(a)=0$ iff $M_1(x_1)=M_1(a)$. This was not an assumption I made, it follows from the original assumption. We subtract to get something in the null space since any vector v with $M_1(v)=0$ is in the null space of $M_1$.

Comment: I got it, thanks.